# ORA-1691: unable to extend lobsegment

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, ddl

I'm getting this error:

```
ORA-1691: unable to extend lobsegment ABC.SYS_LOB0014859757C00018$$ by 1280 in tablespace              ABC
```

The tablespace is build like the folowing:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE "ABC" DATAFILE 
  '/ora/db/user/abc1.db' SIZE 4194304000,
  '/ora/db/user/abc2.db' SIZE 4194304000,
  '/ora/db/user/abc3.db' SIZE 4194304000,
  '/ora/db/user/abc4.db' SIZE 4194304000
  LOGGING ONLINE PERMANENT BLOCKSIZE 8192
  EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL UNIFORM SIZE 10485760 SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT AUTO
```

How can I extend the tablespace? Do I need to restart db after extending?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend a tablespace by adding an additional datafile to it or by extending an existing one. Since you currently seem to have a convention of uniformly sized files, I'd just add another one:

```
ALTER TABLESPACE "ABC" ADD DATAFILE '/ora/db/user/abc5.db' SIZE 4194304000;
```

This can be done with the database and tablespace online, and there's no need to restart anything.

Comment: Thank you. The size is in bytes?

Comment: @user897237 yes. Although if you wish, you could also specify the size in K, M, G, T, P or E - see the details [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/clauses008.htm#CHDEAIID).

Comment: Ok, and I dont need to create anything (abc5.db) on unix machine?

Comment: @user897237 no, Oracle will create and format the file for you. You just need to make sure that the directory is writable by the oracle user (should be - you already have data files there), and that there's enough free space for the operation.